# When should glDeleteBuffers, glDeleteShader, and glDeleteProgram be used in OpenGL ES 2?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

While working with VBOs in OpenGL ES 2, I came across `glDeleteBuffers`, `glDeleteShader`, and `glDeleteProgram`. I looked around on the web but I couldn't find any good answers to when these methods are supposed to be called. Are these calls even necessary or does the computer automatically delete the objects on its own? Any answers are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every glGen* call should be paired with the appropriate glDelete* call which is called when you are finished with the resource.

The computer will not delete the objects on its own while your application is still running because it doesn't know whether you plan to re-use them later. If you are creating new objects throughout the life of your application and failing to delete old ones, then that's a resource leak which will eventually cause a shutdown of your application due to excessive memory usage.

The computer will delete objects for you when the application terminates, so there's no real benefit to deleting the objects that are permanently required throughout the lifetime of your application, but it is generally considered good practice to have a leak-free clean up.

You can call the glDelete* functions as soon as you are finished with the object (e.g. as soon as you've made your last draw call that uses it). You do not need to worry about whether the object might still be in the GPU's queues or pipelines, that is the OpenGL driver's problem.